# Specifying the file extension produced by zsh process substitution

Tags: shell, zsh, process-substitution

I want to use zsh's process substitution to create a temporary file that can then be read by another program. However, the file it generates has no file extension, so the program reading it refuses to continue.

This can be demonstrated by:

```
$ echo =(ls)
/tmp/zshmgIWvT
```

What I want to happen is it to produce a filename like `/tmp/zshmgIWvT.wav`

Can zsh do this?

Comment: Create and remove the temporary file yourself instead of relying on that "process substitution". eg. `tmp=\`mktemp -t XXXXXX.wav\`; command1 > "$tmp"; command2 "$tmp"; rm "$tmp"`. `=(...)` is not a *process* substitution like `<(...)` or `>(...)` for the simple fact you have to wait for the process to finish before reading or writing to that file. Compare `cat <(echo yes; sleep 1000)` to `cat =(echo yes; sleep 1000)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Somewhere in the depths of `zshparam(1)` one may find:

```
   TMPSUFFIX
          A  filename  suffix which the shell will use for temporary files
          created by process substitutions (e.g., `=(list)').   Note  that
          the  value  should  include  a leading dot `.' if intended to be
          interpreted as a file extension.  The default is not  to  append
          any  suffix,  thus  this  parameter should be assigned only when
          needed and then unset again.
```

So

```
% () { TMPSUFFIX=.wav; print =(ls); unset TMPSUFFIX }
/Users/jhqdoe/tmp/zshsQhnnV.wav
% print $TMPSUFFIX

%
```

You may also want to set `TMPPREFIX` especially on shared systems to help avoid various `/tmp` security flaws.

Comment: Nice find! That's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Or `(){local TMPSUFFIX=.wav; print =(ls)}`